# Meaning of 这么多好吃

Tags: mandarin, expressions

I want to get the correct meaning of this sentence:

> 我恨不得一下子把这么多好吃的都吃完。

I understand this sentence as "I wish to eat up all those delicious things, all at once". I don't fully understand the meaning of `这么多好吃`.

My attempt to decipher it was:

- 好吃 is delicious
- 多 says that there are many delicious (好吃) things
- 这么??

What is the meaning of `这么多好吃`  in that sentence?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- "这么" means "so", "such";
- "这么多" is "so much", "so many";
- "好吃" is delicious;
- "好吃的" is "delicious things" (food in this case).

So "这么多好吃**的**" (note the 的 at the end) is "so much delicious food".

Comment: "东西" is omitted from the end of "这么多好吃的".

Comment: I slightly changed the formatting to make it clearer at first sight, hope you don't mind. If you do, feel free to rollback! Ah one thing: the tag <b></b> is getting deprecated if I remember well, so I changed it into <strong></strong> (it's the same). :)

Comment: @BruceLi: You are probably right. But we don't always realized that as the "xx的" structure so widely used.

Comment: @Alenanno: Thank you very much. I always used 'b' as it is simple. Think I should use 'strong' in the future.

Comment: @fefe I think that strong is preferred because while "b" always means "bold", "strong" means "something important", so in the CSS we can always change it to something else than bold, like underlined, another color, etc... Read this [strong vs bold](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/strong#Bold_vs._Strong)... :) "B" is not deprecated yet, it's still used a lot I guess, but many prefer "strong" for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, "好吃的" here is a noun instead of adj. It means "something delicious". We often use this kind of adj phrase to express a noun. Actually you can understand it as "好吃的东西"or "好吃的食物". But we'd like to omit the noun followed by "的". For another similar example: "好玩的" which means interesting things. You can also say"好玩的东西".

"这么多"here means "so many". "这么多好吃的" means "there are so many delicious food"

Answer (score 0):

"这么" means so much, it shares the same meaning with "那么”.
So "这么多" means "so much/many"